# Pick a random product with high stock

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select a random color of the product but I need the randomness to be weighted towards high stock products. So if the stock is high, I want that product to be picked more often. Here's the table I'm working with:

```
CREATE TABLE `cases` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `color` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `stock` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_deleted` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `cases` (`id`, `status`, `color`, `stock`, `date_deleted`, `deleted_by`) VALUES
(2, 2, 'Black', 20, NULL, NULL),
(3, 2, 'Red', 100, NULL, NULL),
(4, 2, 'Blue', 100, NULL, NULL);
```

And I'm using this php script to test out the distribution. You can also check the query I'm using. I got this from another SO question but its not working right for me. The case Black with low stock gets selected most of the time, everytime.

```
$cases = [];
for ($i=0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    $loadCases = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `cases` WHERE status = 2 AND stock > 0 ORDER BY (RAND()*stock) LIMIT 1");
    $case = mysqli_fetch_assoc($loadCases);

    if(isset($cases[$case['color']]))
        $cases[$case['color']]++;
    else
        $cases[$case['color']] = 1;
}
var_dump($cases);
```

Typical results look like this

```
Array
(
    [Black] => 815
    [Red] => 99
    [Blue] => 86
)
```

I need a better query. Any ideas?

Comment: *if the stock is high, I want that product to be picked more often* Use, for example, `ORDER BY RAND() / stock` - less `stock` will cause greater probability.

Comment: Most fascinating. Why is dividing the answer? I'm not able to figure this out

Comment: Maybe not dividing but multiplying...

Comment: Actually dividing is producing the answers I wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is right but SQL is arranging the results in ascending order by default. So lower values are returned more often. This query solves the problem.

```
SELECT * FROM `cases` WHERE status = 2 AND stock > 0 ORDER BY (RAND()*stock) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

could mind this code:

```
// for example
$blue_stock = 3;
$black_stock = 2;
$gray_stock = 1;
$green_stock = 1;
// this is your colors
$colors = ['blue','black','gray','green'];
$knuth_colors = [];
foreach($colors as $v) {
  switch ($v) {
    case blue: 
      for ($i = 0; $i < $blue_stock; $i++) {
        $knuth_colors[] = 'blue';
      } 
    break;
    ......
  }
}
$i = mt_rand(0, count($knuth_colors) - 1);
// color use
$knuth_color = $knuth_colors[$i];
```